# CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder use in .NET Core

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have another problem about add culture in Linux Docker.

A few years ago, I was able to add `en-JP` using the following code:

```
var newCulture = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder("en-JP", CultureAndRegionModifiers.None);
newCulture.LoadDataFromCultureInfo(english);
newCulture.LoadDataFromRegionInfo(new RegionInfo("JP"));
newCulture.CultureEnglishName = "English (Japan)";
newCulture.CultureNativeName = "English (Japan)";
newCulture.Register();
```

When code is run in .NET Framework 4.8, it works - but it does not work on .NET 6 which run in a Linux Docker container.

Do you have any idea to add culture info in Docker?

Whatever can do it in other docker image

Thank you

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "it does not work". Error message? Callstack? Also, include the contents of your Dockerfile.

Comment: But dotnet core have no sysglobl.dll support for Linux which cannot compile use it in docker